# Build an application into Android system with Android.bp instead of Android.mk

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I need help with Android.bp script used by the new [Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) application build system in AOSP.

I can't build simple HelloWorld application for Android Oreo, with new build scripts Android.bp 
my script:

```
android_app {
   name: "AmpTest",
   certificate: "platform",
   manifest: "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
   srcs: [
       "app/src/main/java/**/*.java"
   ],
   android_resource_dirs: [
       "app/src/main/res"
   ],
   enabled: true
}
```

but i see errors:

```
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja 
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build  -t -b out/soong -d 
out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "core-libart"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "core-oj"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "core-libart"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "ext"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "framework"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "okhttp"
error: packages/apps/AmpTest/Android.bp:4:1: "AmpTest" depends on undefined module "framework-res"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

i tried add
libs: []
static_libs: []

but no luck

Question is: how to create APK with Android.bp?

FYI:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.10.0-42-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-18.3-sylvia
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPM1.171019.011
OUT_DIR=out
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Soong requires knowledge of it's modules dependencies.

That is, if those other modules are in ***mk*** files, Soong will not have knowledge of them, and for the moment there doesn't seem to be a way to expose them.

Hope [this links](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/IjNEMlA5lj4) clarifies the answer's source.

Looks like it's better to stick to ***mk*** files for the moment.